# guzzlehttp throwing error on Laravel project - strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, int given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, guzzle

I am trying to consume a POST API using guzzlehttp in my Laravel project. But I am getting an error on my dev server. This is working perfectly on my local system. $postArray is manipulating correctly both side. This is my Guzzle version in Composer: `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3"`.

Code:

```
     $response = Http::withHeaders([
            "accept: application/json",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ])->post('https://staging.consume.com/testing', $postArray)->json();
```

Error:

> strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, int given

JSON:

```
    {
"message": "strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, int given",
"exception": "TypeError",
"file": "/mnt/drive_1/www/deploy-api-2021-07-29-14-25-12/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php",
"line": 28,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/mnt/drive_1/www/deploy-api-2021-07-29-14-25-12/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php",
        "line": 28,
        "function": "strtolower"
    },
    {
        "file": "/mnt/drive_1/www/deploy-api-2021-07-29-14-25-12/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php",
        "line": 189,
        "function": "caselessRemove",
        "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Utils",
        "type": "::"
    },
    {
        "file": "/mnt/drive_1/www/deploy-api-2021-07-29-14-25-12/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php",
        "line": 455,
        "function": "modifyRequest",
        "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Utils",
        "type": "::"
    },
```

Comment: pass the headers as array `Http::withHeaders([ 'Accept' => 'application/json',  'content-type' => 'application/json' ])`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and when I searched, I arrived at this page.
Here's how I solved it.

```
     $response = Http::withHeaders([
            "accept" => "application/json",
            "content-type" => "application/json"
        ])->post('https://staging.consume.com/testing', $postArray)->json();
```